# How does the name Ilja for a girl sounds in german?

Tags: gender, person-names, connotation

My wife wants to name our daughter Ilja (Ilya) but I think this name is reserved as a Slavic Male name. Is that the connotation in Germany also? What do you think? Are there any female Ilja in germany or europe? How does the name sounds for a girl? Thanks a lot.

Comment: That guy https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ilja_Richter is the most known *Ilja* in Germany. The female form is **Iljina** but that name is not common at all in Germany. If the meaning isn't important but you only like the sound, you may settle on *Ilvy* or *Anja* instead.

Comment: I think Ilja is in the same grey area as names like Kim (Asian male name or short form of Kimberley). On the one hand, Germans generally know the Slavic Ilja, but on the other, names ending in -a are almost always female in Germany, so it would sound natural enough to not raise too many eyebrows, imo.

Comment: I also would say that "Ilja" (or any other spelling, also Ilija etc.) is understood to be primarily for male persons. Although of course, first, gender issues tend to get more open these days, and, second, the name is so rare in Germanistan that perhaps it would be irritating only in rare cases when speaking with a person who is acquainted with slavic culture and knows that this is actually the biblical Elias. I would rather be concerned about how does the name sound in English (as this is becoming a Replace-them-all language, obviuosly): does it sound like "ill" (sick)?

Answer (score 4):

I'm living in Eastern Germany, the area where – especially within the older generations – there is strong connection to Slavic World due to the cultural exchange during the Socialist era. While the aforementioned older Easterners usually percieve Ilja as a male name, Westerners and people who didn't learn Russian etc. guess people with this name to be woman. Some (male) friends of mine with this name often receive letters from offials addressed to some "Frau Ilja B****" what always raises laughter among us. So even here you may get away with it.

Note: In Germany the first name of a child has to match it's gender until  2008. Since then it can also be *neutral*. It also shall not make the child ridiculous are otherwise effect it's growing up negatively, what may the case if you give it a gender-wise inapproriate name. So it may also depend on the person at the Civil Registry (Standesamt) who registers your daughter.

Comment: But the female first name *Maria* is also allowed für boys, if its not the very first name: [Klaus Maria Brandauer](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Klaus_Maria_Brandauer), [Rainer Maria Rilke](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rainer_Maria_Rilke), [Guido Maria Kretschmer](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Guido_Maria_Kretschmer), [Carl Maria von Weber](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Carl_Maria_von_Weber)

Comment: I actually said "the first name of a child must match". But appearantly even this isn't true anymore since 2008.

Comment: "Neutral" names have to accompanied by a second name that clarifies the sex (in Germany). But I would be surprised if you could even pass _Ilja_ as neutral at the "Standesamt". They do not judge by "sound", but by registers and sometimes research. _Ilja_ is quite clearly a boy's name (rank 382 on http://www.beliebte-vornamen.de/jahrgang/j2016/top-500-2016), although some people _who haven't heard it before_ may think otherwise.

Comment: @Matthias As stated before this rule is obsolete as of 2008 (cf. http://blog.beliebte-vornamen.de/2009/01/geschlechtsneutrale-vornamen-ohne-zweitnamen-erlaubt/)

Answer (score 2):

I can't talk about Germany, just about Austria (where I live), but since we speak German in both countries (and in some more countries too), I think that my answer will be correct for Germany too:

First names, that end with -a are always thought to be female in German language.

I give you two examples:

**Andrea**
This name has a greek origin, and it even means *»the brave, the male«* (compare with [Androgen](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Androgen) = male hormons, [Andrology](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Andrology) = Science of male health). This name was used in Italy many centuries before it was used in German spoken countries. And of course it is a male first name in Italy (think of [Andrea Doria](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Andrea_Doria) or [Andrea Bocelli](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Andrea_Bocelli))

But in countries, where German is spoken, it is a female first name ([Andrea Ypsilanti](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Andrea_Ypsilanti) or [Andrea Berg](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Andrea_Berg))

**Nikita**
Another Example is *Nikita*, which is a slavic male first name ([Nikita Khrushchev](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nikita_Khrushchev)) But in the song »Nikita« by Elton John, is Nikita a Girl, and also the main character in the Movie [Nikita](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nikita_(film)) is a woman. Many Girls born after 1985 in German spoken countries (but even more in the Netherlands) are also named »Nikita«.

---

So, if I would read a name like »Ilja Schuster«, I would believe that this is a girls name, becasue of the letter a at the end.

In roman mythology there even is a female Ilja: The Mother of Romulus and Remus, who was raped by Mars, the god of war, is known under two different names: One mane is *»[Rhea Silvia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rhea_Silvia)«*, the other is *»Ilia«*, which is just a form of »Ilja« (I and J was two forms of the same letter in roman alphabet).

Comment: As a german, full ack up to shy of the conclusion. Because of Ilja Richter and the whole slavic male name thing, none of the explanation would change my unguided interpretation that Ilja is a male. That said, the "-a" rule should be taken as a mere heuristic, not a fixed rule.

Comment: @hiergiltdiestfu: I didn't know Ilja Richter before. If I would have read this name 2 hours before, without any context that would reveal this persons gender, I would have been absolutely sure, that this person is a woman.

Comment: Maybe this is, because the first name *Ilja* is very rare in Austria. I know absolutely nobody with this name.

Comment: Yeah, the heuristics you'd have used are not wrong. It might be that Mr Richter is much better known in Germany, which might also indicate that your assumption "I think that my answer will be correct for Germany too" is wrong, but then again, I'm only one data point either :)

Comment: in 2013 only 6 boys in Austria was named *Ilja*: http://diepresse.com/mediadb/namen_2014.pdf Female Iljas are not listed, which means: 4 or less girls got this name in Austria in 2013.

Comment: [Sascha ist sowohl ein männlicher als auch ein weiblicher Vorname. Überwiegend wird er für Männer verwendet.](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sascha) Also Luca, Jona, Elia, Mika, Kolja and Aljoscha are counter examples to the "always" in your second sentence. And if you only take the lyrics of "Nikita" (and forget about the video) it is much more likely that it is about a man, although there remains an ambivalence that might very well be intentional.

Comment: @HubertSchölnast What makes you think that the Nikita from Elton John's song is a girl?

Comment: @Lykanion: The Video: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Tg-Q-Acv4qs Here is a screenshot of Nikita, taken from the video: https://i.stack.imgur.com/ksbVP.png Here is another: https://i.stack.imgur.com/WGtpM.png And a third: https://i.stack.imgur.com/Fp20O.jpg